# Monitoring tool installation without root/sudo privileges and no compilation

Tags: linux, process, monitoring, non-root-user, open-source

I originally planned to use zabbix as a monitoring tool but I found out that I can't use it because it requires root access, and I can't make the compilation either due to the client and security reasons.

I found several other open source monitoring tools, but it all seems to require root/sudo privileges or requires compilation.

Is there any possible monitoring tool I can install on CentOS/Linux and use without any root/sudo access and no compilation?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way out for you, if you have ANY server on which you have root access, would be to use icinga with NSCA and passive checks. You would run the monitoring tool on your root server and submit checks via an encrypted internet connection.

The Documentation [here](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/passivechecks.html), despite being slightly outdated, describes the setup very well.

Also [here's](https://sachinsharm.wordpress.com/2013/08/11/setup-and-configure-nagios-client-nsca-on-centosrhel-6-3/) another good tutorial about that.